# SharePoint 2013 Search Service question

Tags: search

I am ready to create "Search Service Application" in SharePoint 2013. I have few questions before I use the GUI or PowerShell to create search svc app.

1. I have a dedicated VM (SP2013Search) for search
2. How do I provision Search Service App so it uses server from step 1?
3. Also, I read somewhere that I can move SP 2010 existing (non-fast) search DB to 2013. Is that a good idea given SP 2013 search DB schema may be way different than SP 2010 enterprise search (not fast). But I also have bunch of metadata that I created in SP 2010 search and custom scopes. Should I start SP 2013 from scratch and use some other mean to import Managed Metadata and Scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have enough resources on VM( Memory and CPU) then their will
   be no issue.
2. If you use the powershell then you can mentioned it.[check this](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/04/29/creating-and-configuring-a-sharepoint-2013-search-service-application/)
3. If you dont have too much data in 2010 then i would prefer clean 2013( manually create the Scopes etc). Migration is not easy process for search.[check this for migration](http://akforsharepoint.blogspot.com/2014/10/migrate-sharepoint-2010-search-service.html)